# How many bytes is a gigabyte (GB)?

Tags: c

When I convert between 1GB to byte using online tools, I get different answers. For instance, using Google Convertor: `1GB=1e+9` while in another converter I get `1GB= 1073741824`. I suppose the unit is used in different fashion based on whether `1KB=1024B` or `1KB=1000B` (this is Google unit).

How can I know which unit my machine uses using a small C program or function? Does C have a macro for that? I want to do that as my program will possibly be run via various operating systems.

Comment: Why should you machine have a unit? Isn't that something we should define and use?

Comment: By the way where did you found *Google Converter*

Comment: The title is bad. The question is not about the size of byte but about the definition of the *kilo* unit. It can be 1000 (common usage outside computers), or 1024 which is a close power of 2. And it is only a *human* convention...

Comment: There is no such thing as "which unit my machine uses". These units are for human readability

Comment: See Wikipedia on [Kibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) (KiB), Mebibytes (MiB), Gibibytes (GiB), Tebibytes (TiB), Pebibytes (PiB), Exbibytes (EiB), etc.  They're the official names for 1024^n units.

Comment: Try 1GiB next time.

Comment: And adding to that: unfortunately, *KB*, *MB*, *GB* are *often* used in the wrong fashion, actually meaning *KiB*, *MiB*, *GiB*. In short: Google is correct.

Comment: Question is not about programming, but OP didn't realize that. Move it with a better title?

Comment: Concerning this, it is important to mention the resp. XKCD comic: [Kilobyte](https://xkcd.com/394/)

Comment: @tilz0R: In the search box in your browser, if you have Google as your search engine, you could say `1 GiB` and it would come up with a converter with lots of options.  You can do all sorts of calculations in Google like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two tools are converting two different units.
`1 GB  = 10^9` bytes while `1 GiB = 2^30` bytes.

Try using google converter with `GiB` instead of `GB` and the mystery will be solved.

The following will help you understand the conversion a little better.

```
Factor  Name    Symbol  Origin  Derivation   Decimal
 2^10   kibi    Ki  kilobinary: (2^10)^1    kilo: (10^3)^1
 2^20   mebi    Mi  megabinary: (2^10)^2    mega: (10^3)^2
 2^30   gibi    Gi  gigabinary: (2^10)^3    giga: (10^3)^3
 2^40   tebi    Ti  terabinary: (2^10)^4    tera: (10^3)^4
 2^50   pebi    Pi  petabinary: (2^10)^5    peta: (10^3)^5
 2^60   exbi    Ei  exabinary:  (2^10)^6    exa:  (10^3)^6
```

Note that the new prefixes for binary multiples are not part of the International System of Units (**SI**). However, for ease of understanding and recall, they were derived from the SI prefixes for positive powers of ten. As shown in the table, the name of each new prefix is derived from the name of the corresponding SI prefix by retaining the first two letters of the **SI** prefix and adding the letters `bi`.

There's still a lot of confusion on the usage of `GB` and `GiB` in fact very often `GB` is used when `GiB` should or was intended to be. 
Think about the hard drives world:
Your operating system assumes that `1 MB` equals `1 048 576 bytes` i.e. `1MiB`. Drive manufacturers consider (correctly) `1 MB` as equal to `1 000 000` bytes. Thus if the drive is advertised as `6.4` GB (`6 400 000 000 bytes`) the operating system sees it as approximately 6.1 GB `6 400 000 000/1 048 576 000` = ~`6.1 GiB`

[Take a look at this for more info on prefixes for binary units](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html) 
and [this on metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix).

Comment: For kilo it should be a lower case `k`

Comment: I think that upper case is right. take a look at this paper http://www.ieee802.org/secmail/pdf00106.pdf

Comment: Wow. You're right. Thank you for the hint. While it is `kB` they named the binary version `KiB`.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a confusion of units. There are actually two prefixes `G` for `10⁹` and `Gi` for `2³⁰`. Bytes should usually be measured with the second, so the correct writing would be `GiB`.

Answer (score 0):

- The “gibibyte” is a multiple of the unit byte for Digital
  Information.
- The binary prefix gibi means 2^30, therefore one gibibyte is equal to
  1073741824 bytes = 1024 mebibytes.
- The unit symbol for the gibibyte is GiB. It is one of the units with
  binary prefixes defined by the International Electrotechnical
  Commission (IEC) in 1998.
- The “gibibyte” is closely related to the Gigabyte (GB), which is
  defined by the IEC as 10^9 bytes = 1000000000 bytes, 1GiB ≈ 1.024GB.
  1024 Gibibytes are equal to One Tebibyte.
- In the context of computer memory, Gigabyte and GB are customarily
  used to mean 1024^3 (2^30) bytes, although not in the context of data
  transmission and not necessarily for Hard Drive size.

[image]