# Mac terminal zip: Size limit parameter does not work properly

Tags: macos, terminal, zip

I need to compress a huge folder into multiple zip files, but each of them should not exceed the size of 1 gigabyte.

I found the following command

```
zip -r -s 1g MyZipFile.zip folderToCompress/
```

But the resulted files do exceed the size of 1 gb:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1073741824 14 Feb 15:40 MyZipFile.z01
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1073741824 14 Feb 15:42 MyZipFile.z02
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1073741824 14 Feb 15:41 MyZipFile.z03
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1073741824 14 Feb 15:42 MyZipFile.z04
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1073741824 14 Feb 15:43 MyZipFile.z05
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  1073741824 14 Feb 15:43 MyZipFile.z06
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   865071084 14 Feb 15:44 MyZipFile.zip
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i guess you see the used disksize, that is different to the size of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` appears to be limiting the size to [1 Gibibyte, not 1 Gigabyte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493178/how-many-bytes-is-a-gigabyte-gb) when you specify the `-s 1g` argument.

1GiB = 2^30 = 1073741824 bytes, which is why you're seeing that number instead of 1GB = 10^9 = 1000000000 bytes. I got the same result trying to zip a multi-GB folder on my own macOS High Sierra desktop. [macOS since Snow Leopard handles file sizes according to standard Gigabytes](https://www.macworld.com/article/1142471/snow_leopard_math.html), so it must be `zip` that is operating using Gibibytes instead. The [zip man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) states that you can only specify an argument for `-s` in KiB, MiB, GiB, or TiB.

So, if you want exactly 1GB to be the size limit, you'd have to find some way to specify a size in KiB, MiB, GiB, or TiB which corresponds to 1000000000 bytes. I don't think that's possible; using a [MiB to GB converter](https://www.gbmb.org/mib-to-gb), the closest I could get to 1GB was 953.67431 MiB, and `zip` doesn't allow you to specify an `-s` argument that isn't a whole number.